# Issue in string formatting with c#

Tags: c#, string, format

datatable DT with 4 column col1,col2,col3,col4.

```
str = String.Format("{0,-30}{0,-30}{0,-30}{0,-30}", "Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4");
```

if we write str to a file it will generate the output

```
Col1                         Col2                         Col3                         Col4
```

I need to do it programatically

```
string str = "";
Boolean fst = true;
string q = Convert.ToString('"');
string frmt = "";
foreach (DataColumn co in DT.Columns)
{

    if (fst)
    {
        colname = colname + q + co.ColumnName + q;
        fst = false;
    }
    else
    {
        colname = colname + "," + q + co.ColumnName + q;
    }

    frmt = frmt + "{0,-30}";
}
str = String.Format(frmt, colname);
```

here value of `frmt="{0,-30}{0,-30}{0,-30}{0,-30}";`
value of `colname="Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4";`

But if I write str to file it gives bad output. Any pointers on how to achive it ?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.. the format you gave would yield:

```
Col1          Col1         Col1          Col1
```

Also, the String.Format() method expects an array of objects as parameters.   What you're passing it is a single string, with words separated by commas.

Why not just do something like:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder()

foreach (DataColumn co in DT.Columns)
   sb.Append(String.Format("{0,-30}", co.ColumnName));

return sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Please see the example in msdn  String  header = String.Format("{0,-12}{1,8}{2,12}{1,8}{2,12}{3,14}","City", "Year", "Population", "Change (%)")

Comment: am just trying to create this input programatically

Comment: Your second argument is just one string, not the 4 separate strings in that example.

Comment: @ Mike Precup if I print the second  argument using a messageBox i can see it as 4 seperate strings in quotes, just as in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your requirment but this may be what you need

```
string frmt = "";
int columnCount = 0;
var values = new List<string>();
foreach (DataColumn co in DT.Columns)
{
    values.Add(co.ColumnName);
    frmt += string.Format("{0}{2}, -30{1}", "{", "}", columnCount);
    columnCount++;
}
string str = string.Format(frmt, values.ToArray());
```

Comment: actually, the last line would have to be:  `str = String.Format(frmt, values.ToArray());`

Comment: @Curt, whoops, Thanks, updated , `String.Join` allows IEnumerable, I thought `String.Format` was the same :)

Comment: There's a fundamental problem that the parameter ID in the format string is always zero (even in the OP example), so the resultant string will just be the first columnname repeated as many times as there are columns:  i.e., only the FIRST parameter will be used.

Comment: @sa_ddam213
Thanks, but it tabkes only the first value of the aray that is col1 only

Comment: @Curt, yeah, I really don't understand what the requirement is in this case, and I am away from VisualStudio so I am writing directly in the answer, LOL, just trying to help :) thanks for the input

Comment: @Flins, sorry about that, I am unable to test my answer right now, but I have made an edit that may work :)